# How do I cluster my data in my React project using deck.gl layers?

Tags: google-bigquery, deck.gl

We are using the Carto builder to visualize data from Google BigQuery. I have been employed to build a project similar to the Carto builder to add more functionality that the builder does not provide.

I am stuck with figuring out how to aggregate data in my React application. I am using deck.gl to display layers on my map to visualize the data.

I am currently using a ScatterPlotLayer as it looks the closest to what the builder has. However my data does not aggregate when I zoom in/out. I am trying to figure out how to achieve this.

What it should look like:

**Zoomed out**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9v1K.png)

**Zoomed In**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUS77.png)

What it currently looks like:
**Zoomed out**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO4BO.png)

**Zoomed In**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvv8c.jpg)

As you can see the data does not get aggregated and instead displays different points on their specified latitude & longitude.

The Carto builder uses Deck.gl for it's layers. So it should be possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have looked at the deck.gl documentation for the following layers:

- ContourLayer
- GridLayer
- GPUGridLayer
- CPUGridLayer
- HexagonLayer
- ScreenGridLayer
- HeatmapLayer

However none of these display as circles nor have a way to change the 2D/3D animations used.